# create sql view with case

Tags: sql

I have a table named VWDRSSTA and it has the following fields
SYSTEM,
EREIGNIS;
DATUM_ZEIT,
ANTRAGSNUMMER,VORGANGSNUMMER,VERS_NR_INT,
DOK_ART,
DUNKEL

I am looking to create a view of this table with a filter in two fields DOK_ART and DUNKEL using CASE statement. Here is what I tried doing

```
CREATE VIEW VWDRSSTA_VIEW As
SELECT SYSTEM, EREIGNIS, DATUM_ZEIT, ANTRAGSNUMMER, VORGANGSNUMMER, VERS_NR_INT,
CASE 
 WHEN EREIGNIS = 'EIN-ES' AND DOK_ART = 'EN' Then 'EN'
ELSE ''
END
CASE
 WHEN EREIGNIS = 'POL_AN' AND DUNKEL = 1 Then 1
ELSE ''
END
FROM VWDRSSTA;
```

Which is going wrong. How can I achieve the above?

Comment: Show us the exact error code you are getting. However it seem you forget to name de `case column`, when you create a view, all the columns must have a unique name (in most of dbms). You must change `CASE 
 WHEN EREIGNIS = 'EIN-ES' AND DOK_ART = 'EN' Then 'EN'
ELSE ''
END` to `CASE 
 WHEN EREIGNIS = 'EIN-ES' AND DOK_ART = 'EN' Then 'EN'
ELSE ''
END AS MyCaseColumn1,` Take notice of the last comma too

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You are also missing a comma in between those `CASE` expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FROCE VIEW VWDRSSTA_VIEW As
SELECT SYSTEM, EREIGNIS, DATUM_ZEIT, ANTRAGSNUMMER, VORGANGSNUMMER, VERS_NR_INT,
      CASE
        WHEN EREIGNIS = 'EIN-ES' AND DOK_ART = 'EN'
        THEN 'EN'
        ELSE ''
      END AS DOK_ART,
      CASE
        WHEN EREIGNIS = 'POL_AN' AND DUNKEL = 1
        THEN 1
        ELSE ''
      END AS DUNKEL           
    FROM
      VWDRSSTA;
```